# How to pass bearer token API in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have an API which has Authorization has bearer token. I tested in post man and it's working. However, it's not working when I used web activity in the ADF.

[image]

I am passing the url in the URL section. Created new header, typed Authorization and gave value "Bearer token"

Getting below error

```
Error
Troubleshoot activity failures
{
    "errorCode": "2108",
    "message": "{\"error\":{\"type\":\"invalid_request_error\",\"message\":\"Request forbidden by administrative rules. Please make sure your request has an acceptable User-Agent header.\",\"documentation_url\":\"https://developer.dentally.co\"}}",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Web1",
    "details": []
}
```

Can anyone please advise?

Comment: The method used is indeed a correct way to give bearer token. [This image](https://i.imgur.com/3KBdfVw.png) is a reference where I have tested passing bearer token in the same method as yours and got the correct output. Please recheck if the bearer token given is the correct one.

Comment: @SaideepArikontham. Thanks for your reply. I created linked service for rest api and used copy data activity. Connection is working and I can see the preview data from the source. I am copying the data into csv in data lake. However, when I test the pipeline, I am getting error 2200

Comment: @SaideepArikontham  This is the error I am getting. {
    "errorCode": "2200",
    "message": "Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=RestCallFailedWithClientError,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Rest call failed with client error, status code 401 Unauthorized, please check your activity settings.You did not provide a valid API token. You need to provide your API token in the Authorization header, using Bearer auth (e.g. 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_SECRET_TOKEN').

Comment: @SaideepArikontham I can see preview data, not sure why it's saying unauthorized. I used the same API and read the data in Python. Can you please advise?

Comment: Have you provided the necessary bearer token in the REST linked service? And, it is odd that preview is showing the data and running the pipeline is throwing a 401 Unauthorized error.

Comment: @SaideepArikontham yes i gave correct bearer token in the rest api linked service

Comment: I got the 401 Unauthorized error only when I completely skipped giving Authorization header. Both the preview and pipeline failed. Not sure why preview is working but pipeline fails in your case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I reproduced the same in my environment. I successfully generated a bearer Token with  Postman.

To solve the above `error code:2200`. Please follow the below approach.

[image]

- I used the same URL with web Activity and generated a bearer Token in the Azure data factory.
  [image]
- Generate bearer Token as shown below:

[image]

- Connect Web activity 2 with newly created Web1 activity

[image]

- Add dynamic expression : `Bearer @{activity('Web2').output.data.Token}`

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[Sample Rest API URL for testing with authentication by Ashok Patel](https://www.appsloveworld.com/sample-rest-api-url-for-testing-with-authentication)