# Azure Data Factory - Web activity with header value containing comma failing

Tags: azure-data-factory

We are trying to ingest data from Amazon Selling Partner API.  We currently have an azure function that signs our request and returns the header values.  The authorization header contains commas in it and the comma causes the activity to fail on the client side.

Here is an exampleof the authorization header:

```
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE/20130524/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request,SignedHeaders=date;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date;x-amz-storage-class,Signature=98ad721746da40c64f1a55b78f14c238d841ea1380cd77a1b5971af0ece108bd
```

To reproduce, create a new pipeline and add a web activity.  Enter "http://www.google.com" for the url with the method GET.  Add a header like above.
[image]

You should get the following error:

```
Error calling the endpoint 'http://www.google.com'. Response status code: 'NA - Unknown'. More details: Exception message: 'NA - Unknown [ClientSideException] The format of value 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE/20130524/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request,SignedHeaders=date;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date;x-amz-storage-class,Signature=98ad721746da40c64f1a55b78f14c238d841ea1380cd77a1b5971af0ece108bd' is invalid.'.

Request didn't reach the server from the client. This could happen because of an underlying issue such as network connectivity, a DNS failure, a server certificate validation or a timeout.
```

Any work arounds for this?
Thanks,
Scott

Comment: Hi @TXAggie00 - did you end up resolving this issue? I have it too

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Authorization as a header to get data make sure to use bearer in front of the Token.

> **Authorization**    `Bearer < Access Token >`

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results***:

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

For more information **refer** this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73760418/how-to-pass-bearer-token-api-in-azure-data-factory/73763796#73763796) thread .

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the case with Amazon SP-API calls.  This is not a bearer token, it is a special signed authorization string as described in AWS Sigv4 documents.  Please try my example as stated in the question and let me know if it fails for you as well.